# How to display CZML polygons in real time

Tags: cesiumjs

My code changes the value (time, polygon height) of sql to express czml at regular intervals. When czml with interval time between 1:00 and 2:00 moves to a czml file with interval time between 2:00 and 3:00, the error "DeveloperError: Normalized result is not a number" is generated.

How do I connect the 1:00-2:00 czml file to the 2:00-3:00 czml file without errors?

This is my czml file.

```ts
        const exresult = [
          {
            id: "document",
            name: "CZML Custom Properties",
            version: "1.0",
            clock: {
              interval: TotalDate2,
              currentTime: date_re1,
              multiplier: 300,
            },
          },
          {
            id: "water_extrudedheight",
            name: "An object with custom properties",
            properties: {
              constant_property: true,
              population_sampled: {
                number: [date_re1, result6[0], date_re2, result6[1]],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            id: "colorado",
            name: "Colorado",
            polygon: {
              positions: {
                cartographicDegrees: [
                  128.818153,
                  37.699167,
                  0,
                  128.189289,
                  37.698488,
                  0,
                  128.818186,
                  37.696908,
                  0,
                  128.814783,
                  37.697982,
                  0,
                ],
              },
              material: {
                solidColor: {
                  color: {
                    rgba: [0, 255, 0, 150],
                  },
                },
              },
              height: 208.652,
              extrudedHeight: 208.652,
            },
          },
        ];
```

The first czml is expressed without errors even if it is repeated.

However, if the interval time and the number time at the bottom of population_sampled change, the error "DeveloperError: Normalized result is not a number" will occur.

I thought the interval time was a problem, so I set the interval time to 24 hours and set only the value of number to be different, but if the interval time and the time size of number are not the same, I confirmed that the same error appears.

Comment: Could you make a [Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/) demo with two adjacent CZMLs, to reproduce this error?

Comment: I'm not sure because it's the process of importing from server.js and cesiumviewer.js to ajax.

This is that link.
               bit.ly/3GRuL5S